# CENTOS 7 disk cloned from image won't boot. Need new BIOS?

Tags: centos, boot, bios, disk-image, clonezilla

I'm trying to make my brand-new HP Z4G4 workstation boot to CENTOS 7 from its SSD drive, but after it indicated which kernel it's using, spins its wheel, and shows its faint "7" on the screen, it goes to emergency mode. I purchased it as a Windows machine that would boot to Windows from SSD.

- I booted it to Windows once to make sure the system was basically functioning.
- Then I swapped out the original Windows SSD for a new blank SSD, onto which I installed a CENTOS 7 from an image using Clonezilla.

Q: Do I need a new BIOS to get it to boot? Is there something else I need to do?

I'm mystified because I've used this same Clonezilla USB to install this exact same image from USB to the same kind and size of SSD drive on a different HP Z4G4 computer. But the computer I performed this with before had originally been configured for CENTOS, not Windows, suggesting to me that the difference with the new computer lies with the BIOS, but I don't know that for sure, and I don't know how to update the BIOS.

Also, the new computer isn't hooked up to the network yet. I was going to configure its network settings using the graphical tools I'm used to in CENTOS. I suppose I could configure them on the command line in emergency mode, but I'm unsure that would help.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might be a lot of things - from secureboot to LUKS disk encryption with hardware secrets, to your laptop not having scanned the SSD for me uefi boot loaders and hence trying to load the wrong thing... Cloning might not be as trivial as it sounds

Comment: Any suggestions on where to start? Nothing is encrypted, and the system knows enough to boot to the latest CENTOS kernel installed by the image. It's clearly able to start booting to CENTOS because I see the big, faint "7" on the screen while it spins its wheel. But instead of presenting the normal login window, it goes to emergency mode.